# 22.04 - Power saver mode seems to be deactivated as soon as the charger is connected

Tags: power-management, 22.04, fan

After upgrading from 20.04 to 22.04, a loud fan noise is disturbing as soon as the charger of the notebook (Asus UX331) is connected. The power-saving mode setting is then apparently ignored. This means putting up with noise for an hour until the battery is full and then unplugging the power cable - from then on there is silence. It would be great if someone knows a better solution.

Comment: Have you confirmed that there are not different power profiles for “Plugged in” and “On battery” in your settings? An upgrade may have cleared any customizations as part of the process 

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the right hint. tlp was running. After removing tlp it still didn't work, but the reverse was successful: remove power-profiles-daemon & install tlp & preset the battery mode. Since then, it has been wonderfully quiet, even when AC connected. You made my day!